# Facebook Post to wall from

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I've a facebook application and a group for that application. Is it possible to make the application automatically post on the group. As far as posting is concern, its ok but how to give the application permission to post on the group?

I'm using facebook graph explorer to test this

https://graph.facebook.com/GROUP_ID/feed, method Post and adding a field 'link' with URL 'http://www.google.com' and selecting application as the application i want. I'm getting this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 2
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfectly working. How you are selecting application as the application you want? It should be Graph Api Application.

Answer (score 0):

The error doesn’t exactly say this, but I’d guess it’s thrown because your not sending a valid access token.

Get a user access token from one of the users that is allowed to post to that group’s wall.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a permission problem and the permission needed was user_groups,publish_stream